# How do I check if a selector contains sub-selector X in SASS?

Tags: sass

here's the function I'm trying to create :

```
@function contains-selector ($selector, $subselector) {
  @return str_index($selector,$subselector);
}
```

but I believe it will return true even for the `'.weird-selecto'` case that you see below, which is wrong.

example :

```
#some .long .weird-selector {
}

//should return true
contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '.weird-selector') 

//should return false
contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '.weird-selecto')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach although it looks a bit complicated

```
@function contains-selector ($selector, $subselector) {
  $start_index: str-index($selector, $subselector);
  $selector_found: null;
  @if ($start_index == null) {
    $selector_found: false;
  } @else {
    $end_index: $start_index + str-length($subselector) - 1;
    @while( ($end_index <= str-length($selector)) and (str-slice($selector, $end_index, $end_index) != ' ')) {
      $end_index: $end_index + 1;
    }
    $word: str-slice($selector, $start_index, $end_index - 1);
    $selector_found: if($word == $subselector, true, false);
  }
  @return $selector_found;
}
```

Using the function in the following situations

```
@debug contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '#arbitrary-text'); //false
@debug contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '.wei');            //false
@debug contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '#some');           //true
@debug contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '.weird-selector'); //true
@debug contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '.weird-select');   //false
```

The way `str-index` works is that it gets the *starting index* of a *substring* found within a string or `null` if can't find a matching *substring*.

`str_index('.weird-selector', '.where')` returns **null** because the substring `where` can't be found in `weird-selector` while `str_index('.weird-selector', '.weird-selec');` returns **1** because the substring `.weird-selec` can be found at the 1st position of the string `.weird-selector`

In the **if** condition of the method, if the *subselector* is not found in the *selector*, the `str-index` returns null and the method returns false
`@debug contains-selector('#some .long .weird-selector', '#arbitrary-text'); //false`

In the **else** block, we know that the *subselector* found in the *selector* is similar but **not** if they are the same.
Using `str_index('#some .weird-selector .long', '.weird-selec')`, we can see `weird-selec` is in the string but the **actual word** in the string is `weird-selector`.  So the loop in the block is responsible for getting the `end_index` of the **word** in the string. Once the *word* has been found, it is compared to the *subselector* and the method returns true if they match or false otherwise.

Hope this helps :)